# Alias to connect to AWS instance via SSH not working

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, amazon-web-services, bash-alias

I made an alias to make it easier to connect to my AWS EC2 instance. Although there is an error. Here is the code in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias aws_connect=‘ssh -i /path/to/keyfile.pem  ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx’
```

When I type "aws_connect in the terminal, this is what comes out: `-bash: “ssh: command not found`. This is the output when I type `source ~/.bash_profile`:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ username$ source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: alias: -i: not found
-bash: alias: /path/to/keyfile.pem: not found
-bash: alias: ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx”: not found
```

Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Comment: Is that a cut and paste?  If so, the quote marks are wrong - they should be `'` not `‘’`

Comment: That worked. OS X automatically makes `'` into `‘’`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using ssh config for this?

You can achieve this by creating a config file in your `~/.ssh` folder:

`vim ~/.ssh/config` and then add something like this:

`Host example
        HostName Server_IP_or_hostname
        User SSH_USER
        IdentityFile ~/path/to_your_key`

And then when you want to ssh all you have to do is type:

`ssh example`

<2cents>

Comment: Ah, I didn't know this was possible. I'm new to OS X. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. This works in both OSX and Linux and is really helpful when you have quite few servers to connect on :-)